# Java : get all properties of an object recursively

Tags: java, algorithm

This is pure Java core. I have a `class Message` like this :

```
class Message {

   private int id;
   private String status;
   private List<Message> children;

   //getters, setters, methods

}
```

Each `Message` object has a list of children of same type `Message`. And each child has a list of children etc...

Is there a way to get all chidren (and children of children) and put them into a `List` ?

Comment: You could use recursion or use a queue to get all the messages.

Answer (score 1):

Add a method to recursively stream the children:

```
public Stream<Message> children() {
    Stream<Message> result = Stream.of(this);
    if (children != null) {
        result = Stream.concat(result,
                children.stream().flatMap(Message::children));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Then call `message.children().collect(toList())` on any message to convert it to a list of children.

Comment: OK thanks but I got NPE, probably because some messages don't have children so "null" value for children.

Comment: So just return `Stream.of(this)` if `children == null`.

Comment: it's not that easy because I don't know where exactly the null children are, it could be nested children not just the parent element

Comment: It is that easy.  The recursion will sort that out.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a recursive method in the `Message` class that adds the message and its children to an existing list, like this.

```
public void addToListRecursively(List<Message> toAddTo) {
    toAddTo.add(this);
    for (Message child : children) {
        child.addToListRecursively(toAddTo);
    }
}
```

After this method has run, the list `toAddTo` contains the message that you called it on, plus all its descendants, in depth first order.

Doing it in breadth first order is somewhat trickier.

This assumes that if a `Message` has no children, then `children` is an empty list, rather than null.  If it's possible for `children` to be null, you can put a null check around the for loop.